# Issue adding custom taxonomies to custom post type (PHP)

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have an issue updating custom taxonomies in a custom post type.

Following setup:

1. I have a custom post type 'listing'
2. There are two custom taxonomies connected to 'listing': 'sector' and 'location'.
3. Users can submit a form and WordPress generates a new 'listing'-post with the data.

Now, everything except for the 'sector' and 'location' data works fine and appears in the new listing post (draft).

There must be something wrong in my code/ thinking. Even if I change the values for 'sector' and 'location' to something static (like in the code below) it does not write it to the new post.

```php
            $my_post = array(
                'post_author' => 1,
                'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($params['fieldname6']),
                'post_content' => wp_kses_post($params['fieldname8']),
                'post_type' => 'listing',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(21), 'sector', false );
    
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', $params['fieldname18'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'phone_link', 'tel:' . $params['fieldname18'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'email', $params['fieldname17'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'email_link', 'email:' . $params['fieldname17'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'website', $params['fieldname7'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'address', $params['fieldname14'] . ', ' . $params['fieldname15'] . ', ' . $params['fieldname16'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'placement', $params['fieldname1'], true);
```

EDIT: I added the full code. I also changed the approach to use wp_set_object_terms. I've tried IDs and slugs, true and false and changed the taxonomies from hierarchical to non-hierarchical. All to no effect.

To explain the code: I'm using a plugin (Calculated Fields Form) that returns the values of all form field in an array "$params". That part works well anyway. The only line that does not result in the desired outcome is:

```
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(21), 'sector', false );
```

Comment: have you tried term IDs instead of term slugs? Your code looks incomplete, I can see the `$my_post` variable, but there is no `wp_insert_post` call or functions using it, and no information about where/when this code runs. Can you edit your question to include the missing code? **Are these taxonomies hierarchical?**

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you! I updated the question.

Comment: note that according to the docs for `wp_insert_term` the terms must be term IDs if it is a hierarchical taxonomy. This is because different terms can have the same slug if they have different parents

Comment: @TomJNowell that's what I think I do in the code line:  
`wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(21), 'sector', false );`

where 21 is the ID of one of the terms in the taxonomy.